# puppeteerでflashを有効にするには？

Tags: node.js, flash, puppeteer

OSはwindows7 64bitです。
puppeteerでflashを有効にするには、どのようにしたらよろしいでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

私も同じ問題でハマりました。
puppeteer.launchでオプションをつければ可能なようです。

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        args: [
            '--ppapi-flash-path= {FLASH_PATH}',
        ]
    });
```

puppeteerのブラウザはChromiumですので、Chromiumで使えるflash playerが必要です。
もしなければ[Adobeのサイト](https://get.adobe.com/jp/flashplayer/otherversions/)からPPAPIのものをダウンロードしてPathに指定してください。

次に、Flash Playerを使うにはFlash Playerを許可するサイトを登録しなければなりません。
それこそオプションで指定できれば良いのですが、残念ながら私にはわかりませんでした。
以下のアドレスで設定画面に移動し、地味にDOMを操作して書き込むしかないでしょうかね...

```
chrome://settings/content/flash
```

Comment: flash本体は、pepflashplayer.dllで検索すると見つかりました。